# I'm wondering why I'm getting a TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python, list, dictionary, typeerror

I'm trying to make a list of names based off the last number in the values list. The new list will be ordered based on highest number to lowest number but is a list of the names.

```
folks = {'Leia': [28, 'F', 'W', False, True, 'Unemployed',1], 
        'Junipero': [15, 'M', 'E', False, False, 'Teacher', 0.21158336054026594], 
        'Sunita': [110, 'D', 'E', True, False, 'Business', 0.9834949767416051], 
        'Issur': [17, 'F', 'O', True, False, 'Service', 0.7599396397686616], 
        'Luitgard': [0, 'D', 'U', True, True, 'Unemployed', 0.8874638219100845], 
        'Rudy': [112, 'M', 'W', True, True, 'Tradesperson', 0.6035917636433216], 
        'Ioudith': [20, 'D', 'W', True, True, 'Medical', 0.24957574519928294], 
        'Helmi': [109, 'D', 'M', False, False, 'Service', 0.20239906854483214], 
        'Katerina': [108, 'M', 'W', False, True, 'Student', 0.3046268530221382], 
        'Durai': [106, 'M', 'U', True, False, 'Business', 0.32332997497778493], 
        'Euphemios': [83, 'M', 'L', True, True, 'Banker', 0.17369577419188664], 
        'Lorinda': [8, 'F', 'E', False, True, 'Retail', 0.6667783756618852], 
        'Lasse': [30, 'D', 'U', True, True, 'Business', 0.6716420300452077], 
        'Adnan': [117, 'D', 'U', True, False, 'Banker', 0.7043759366238305], 
        'Pavica': [112, 'F', 'L', False, False, 'Business', 0.5875152728319836], 
        'Adrastos': [118, 'F', 'L', False, True, 'Service', 0.0660146284846359], 
        'Kobus': [49, 'D', 'S', False, False, 'Service', 0.4738056051140088], 
        'Daniel': [115, 'D', 'L', False, True, 'Service', 0.5182765931408372], 
        'Samantha': [97, 'D', 'W', True, True, 'Medical', 0.07082409148069169], 
        'Sacagawea': [28, 'F', 'U', True, True, 'Medical', 0.29790328657890996], 
        'Ixchel': [26, 'F', 'S', False, False, 'Business', 0.22593704520870372], 
        'Nobutoshi': [31, 'M', 'W', False, True, 'Business', 0.37923896100469956], 
        'Gorou': [55, 'M', 'B', True, True, 'Banker', 0.8684653864827863], 
        'Keiko': [34, 'M', 'L', False, True, 'Student', 0.02499269016601946], 
        'Seong-Su': [1, 'M', 'M', False, True, 'Retail', 0.3214997836868769], 
        'Aya': [41, 'M', 'B', True, True, 'Teacher', 0.3378161065313626], 
        'Okan': [11, 'D', 'W', True, True, 'Banker', 0.35535128959244744], 
        'Mai': [31, 'F', 'M', False, False, 'Service', 0.7072299366468716], 
        'Chaza-el': [84, 'D', 'E', True, True, 'Teacher', 0.263795143996962], 
        'Estera': [79, 'M', 'U', True, False, 'Tradesperson', 0.09970175216521693], 
        'Dante': [82, 'M', 'L', True, False, 'Unemployed', 0.2126494288577333], 
        'Leofric': [68, 'F', 'B', True, False, 'Unemployed', 0.19591887643941486], 
        'Anabelle': [63, 'M', 'B', False, False, 'Teacher', 0.3558324357405023], 
        'Harsha': [119, 'D', 'O', False, True, 'Retail', 0.3359989642837887], 
        'Dionisia': [92, 'F', 'B', True, False, 'Doctor', 0.42704604164789706], 
        'Rajesh': [55, 'F', 'M', True, False, 'Doctor', 0.485752225148387], 
        'Scilla': [60, 'F', 'M', False, False, 'Student', 0.7294089528796434], 
        'Arsenio': [10, 'D', 'L', False, True, 'Teacher', 0.0819890866210915]}


def generate_prioritized_list(unordered_people):
    nums=[]
    for i in folks:
        nums.append(folks[i][6])
    nums.sort(reverse=True)
    for i in nums:
        names=[]
        for name in folks:
            if i in folks[name][6]:
                names.append(folks[i])
    for i in names:
        print(i)
        

print(generate_prioritized_list(folks))
```

I'm trying to get a list of the names ordered highest to lowest by the last value in the list each persons attributes.

Comment: `if i in folks[name][6]` folks[name][6] is a single integer.  It makes no sense to ask if something is **in** an integer.  Did you actually mean to check if they are **equal**?

Comment: thank you this was an over site on my behalf. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `key` argument to the `sorted` function

```
sorted(folks, key=lambda x: folks[x][-1])[::-1]
```

- `sorted` pulls the keys out of the dictionary
- `key=lambda x: folks[x][-1]` determines how to sort those keys
- `[::-1]` reverses the list.

I get:

```
['Leia',
 'Sunita',
 'Luitgard',
 'Gorou',
 'Issur',
 # ... 
 'Estera',
 'Arsenio',
 'Samantha',
 'Adrastos',
 'Keiko']
```

Comment: reverse is implemented in sorted: `sorted(folks, key=lambda x: folks[x][-1], reverse=True)`

Comment: @Ovski on my local version of python, using `reversed` raises a `TypeError` in this command

Comment: that is very strange. I just tested it in a 3.10 environment and it works as expected. What Python version are you running?